# How can a MPVolumeView be positioned?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm having trouble positioning a MPVolumeView. In the viewDidLoad method of my viewController I have this code:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
MPVolumeView *myVolumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame: self.volumeView.bounds];
[self.volumeView addSubview: myVolumeView];
```

In the storyboard I've added the volumeView and I have hooked it up to the controller.
I'm including two screenshots: one of the storyboard and one of how the view looks when it is running on my phone.

How can I position the MPVolumeView in the volumeView?
[image: storyboard]
[image: how it looks look on my device]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to create an `MPVolumeView` in Interface Builder instead of in code. You can do this by dragging a custom `UIView` into the XIB, configuring it as needed, and then changing its class to `MPVolumeView`.

Comment: but I still would like to know why my code didn't work... :-)

Comment: Is `self.volumeView` the red box? I suspect your outlets might not be hooked up correctly.